# cell hight is decreasing when the button in the expanded tableview cell is clicked which is not required.

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have tableview with section and rows.When i click on the sections rows will show when i click again on the section rows will disappear.

In the expand row  I have view in that  I have 2 labels whos hight is dynamic,I am using auto resize for that.I am calculating the 2 labels hight.I am calculating the hight of the labels ands depends on the i am getting the row hight.

when rows are loading when the section is clicked the the cell showing with perfect hight.(note for row indexpath==0 i am taking one hight other i am taking same hight).

When I click on the button which in the expanded cell at some indexpath say indexpath==1,I am reloading 1st indexpath.

The code under add button.

```
NSIndexPath* rowToReload = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag 
inSection:sectionselect];
  NSLog(@"%@",rowToReload);
    NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rowToReload, nil];
[_tblview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

the code for calculating hight.

```
 -(CGFloat)getLabelHeightForString: (NSString *)string font: (UIFont *)font

 {

CGSize size = CGSizeMake( menudetailscell.typelbl.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT);
NSStringDrawingContext *context = [[NSStringDrawingContext alloc] init];
CGSize boundingBox = [string boundingRectWithSize:size

                                          options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin

                                       attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font}

                                          context:context].size;
size = CGSizeMake(ceil(boundingBox.width), ceil(boundingBox.height));
return size.height;

}
```

hightforrow at indexpath

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    if (indexPath.row==0) {
    menudetailscell.toplbl.hidden=NO;
    NSArray *aarr=[menuarray[indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"menu"];
   NSString *namestr=[[aarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"];
     UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat-Regular" size:15.0];
    NSString *desc=[[aarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"description"];
    UIFont *desfont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Rubik-Light" size:13.0];
    CGFloat size = [self getLabelHeightForString: namestr font:font];
    CGFloat dissize = [self getLabelHeightForString:desc  font:desfont];

    return 90+size+dissize-40;
}
else{
   // menudetailscell.toplbl.hidden=NO;
    NSArray *aarr=[menuarray[indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"menu"];
    NSString *namestr=[[aarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"name"];
    UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat-Regular" size:15.0];
    NSString *desc=[[aarr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"description"];
    UIFont *desfont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Rubik-Light" size:13.0];
    CGFloat size = [self getLabelHeightForString: namestr font:font];
    CGFloat dissize = [self getLabelHeightForString:desc  font:desfont];

     menudetailscell.toplbl.hidden=YES;
    return 75+size+dissize-33;

  }
  }
   //cellforrowatindexpath
    UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat-Regular" size:15.0];
 CGFloat size = [self getLabelHeightForString: menudetailscell.typelbl.text font:font];
menudetailscell.typelbl.frame=CGRectMake(menudetailscell.typelbl.frame.origin.x, menudetailscell.typelbl.frame.origin.y, menudetailscell.typelbl.frame.size.width, size);
UIFont *desfont=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Rubik-Light" size:13.0];
CGFloat dissize = [self getLabelHeightForString: 
 menudetailscell.describtionlbl.text font:desfont];menudetailscell.describtionlbl.frame=CGRectMake(menudetailscell.describtionlbl.frame.origin.x, menudetailscell.typelbl.frame.origin.y+size+2, menudetailscell.describtionlbl.frame.size.width, dissize);
```

Thanks for quickresponce.please find the below imgs for quick understanding [image]